# How are "(for) long" and "(for) a long time" different?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

[This is the explanation from Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/long_2)

> **(for) long / (for) a long time**
>
> 1. Both **(for) long** and **(for) a long time** are used as expressions of time. In positive sentences **(for) a long time** is used:
>
> - *We’ve been friends a long time.*
>
> **(For) long** is not used in positive sentences unless it is used with too, enough, as, so, seldom, etc:
>
> - *I stayed out in the sun for too long.*
> - *You’ve been waiting long enough.*
>
> Both **(for) long** and **(for) a long time** can be used in questions, but **(for) long** is usually preferred:
>
> - *Have you been waiting long?*
>
> 2. In negative sentences **(for) a long time** sometimes has a different meaning from **(for) long**. Compare:
>
> - *I haven’t been here for a long time* ( = It is a long time since the last time I was here) and *I haven’t been here long* ( = I arrived here only a short time ago).

In general, I feel headache when reading it because it just says how to use it but does not explain **why?**

Can anyone explain this to me:

**How are "*(for) long*" and "*(for) a long time*" different?**

According to my study, it seems that "**for long**" seems for a short period of time like 4 or 5 hours, while "**for a long time**" seems for a longer period of time like 4 or 5 years.

But I am not sure.

Comment: I don't think there is any logical explanation - that's just how the language has evolved.  What is considered 'a long time' depends on the context, not the grammar. "Have you been waiting long?" and "Have you been living here long?" would expect answers of different orders of magnitude.

Comment: That's an etymology question, and outside the scope of this forum

Comment: @gotube, there is a pattern. It seems like "**for long**" is used for short period of time like "Have you been waiting here for long?" or "You have been watching TV so long" while "**for a long time**" is for longer period of time like "I have been living here for a long time" etc.

Comment: @KateBunting, there is a pattern. It seems like "**for long**" is used for short period of time like "Have you been waiting here for long?" or "You have been watching TV so long" while "**for a long time**" is for longer period of time like "I have been living here for a long time" etc. **Don't you think so?**

Comment: @Tom You asked **why** they are different. That's a question of usage history, which is an off-topic question here. If your intent was to ask the functional differences between the two beyond what's already in the Oxford quote (a **"how"** question), then edit your question to be clear, and include these examples to illustrate what you want

Comment: "Have you been waiting for a long time?" would be perfectly acceptable, I think.

Answer (score 1):

**(for) long** is preferred for statements in the negative:

> I will be busy **for a long time** - *positive*
> I won't be busy **for long** - *negative*

**(for) long** is preferred for questions:

> Have you known him **long**? - *question*
> I have known him **for a long time**. - *statement*

Comment: What about "**he has been a thief for a long time**" (a bad thing) and "**I won't learn English for long**" (a good thing)?

Comment: Oops. The first part of my explanation was incorrect. "he has been a thief for a long time" vs "he hasn't been a thief for long"